# How to create an associative map in golang?

Tags: arrays, go

I'm trying to create an 'associative' map. The issue is that the superMap collects all the values of aMap.
Basically  even if I want to store only one instance of amap on each look I endup storing the current instance plus all the previous loops.  `supermap[value] = amap[value]` . However the snippet below stores `supermap[value] = amap`. The reason is that I can't find any way to fix this. If I delete the old values of aMap after each loop they are deleted from `supermap` as well.

```
  package main

    import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    aData := map[int]string{
        0: "apple",
        1: "samsung",
        2: "htc",
        3: "sony",
    }

    dir := []string{"user", "doc", "bin", "src"}

    aMap := make(map[int]string)
    superMap := make(map[string]map[int]string)

    for k, v := range dir {
        aMap[k] = aData[k]
        superMap[v] = aMap


    }
    hello(superMap)

}

func hello(superMap map[string]map[int]string) {
    fmt.Printf("superMap of user is %v \n", superMap["user"])

    cnt := len(superMap["user"])
    if cnt > 1{


    fmt.Printf("expected only one value received %v", cnt)
    }
}
```

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/lJsJGZ4sP8)

Comment: move `aMap` creation into for loop

Comment: @Arjan that's a gotcha isn't it ? I'm wondering why it's working when you re-initialise the map but doesn't work when you delete it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Arjan said in the comment, you need to move the creation of `aMap` into the for loop.  The reason is because, in the original code you posted you are dealing with one instance of `aMap` in memory.  That means, only one map called `aMap` is created and when you assign another variable to the value of `aMap` you are *assigning a reference*.  This means, any variable that hold a reference (to `aMap`) where state is mutated, will be observed in all other variables also holding the reference because they all resolve to the same object in memory.

When the `aMap` is moved into the for/range loop, this means that 4 individual instances of `aMap` will be created all with their own memory.  Mutating the state of one of those `aMaps` will not affect the others because they are their own objects in memory.  Now, if you took one of those objects and made a reference to it again with another variable then you'd end up in the same boat as the first case.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    aData := map[int]string{
        0: "apple",
        1: "samsung",
        2: "htc",
        3: "sony",
    }

    dir := []string{"user", "doc", "bin", "src"}

    //aMap := make(map[int]string) //only one map instance is created in memory
    superMap := make(map[string]map[int]string)

    for k, v := range dir {
        //multiple map instances are created in memory
        aMap := make(map[int]string)
        aMap[k] = aData[k]
        superMap[v] = aMap

    }

    hello(superMap)
}

func hello(superMap map[string]map[int]string) {
    fmt.Printf("superMap of user is %v \n", superMap["user"])
    cnt := len(superMap["user"])

    if cnt > 1 {
        fmt.Printf("expected only one value received %v", cnt)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not aware how maps are really stored in memory. I'm wondering if this solution doesn't lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Since Go is garbage collected, you will not have a problem with memory leaks with typical code like this.  You don't have to concern yourself too much with the memory details of Go.  What is important is recognizing when you are dealing with references, values and pointers.